# log4j2 does not roll application logs written without log4j

Tags: log4j, log4j2

My log4j2.xml does not delete old logs.
My application writes logs to {sys:LOG_PATH}/onixs/fix/ without log4j (sys:LOG_PATH is a environment variable).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="onixs"
                 fileName="${sys:LOG_PATH}/onixs/engine/engine_log.txt"
                 filePattern="${sys:LOG_PATH}/onixs/archive/engine/engine_log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}.txt"
                 append="true"
                 immediateFlush="false">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS}|%-5.5level|%-20.20thread|%-30.30logger{30}|%msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="nomax">
            <Delete basePath="${sys:LOG_PATH}/onixs/archive/">
                <IfFileName glob="engine_log.*.txt"/>
                <IfLastModified age="1d"/>
            </Delete>
            <Delete basePath="${sys:LOG_PATH}/onixs/fix/">
                <IfAny>
                    <IfFileName glob="*.R*.summary"/>
                    <IfFileName glob="*.state"/>
                </IfAny>
                <IfLastModified age="1d"/>
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <logger name="biz.onixs" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="onixs"/>
    </logger>
   
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

I expect my log4j to roll logs in ${sys:LOG_PATH}/onixs/fix/ every day (IfLastModified age="1d"). But this isn't happening. Could you help me understand why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file pattern says you want the log to roll over every second however your policy indicates you only want to rollover when the application starts. The ifLastModified age="1d" indicates that you only want to keep the previous day's files in the archive folder. It has nothing to do with how frequently rollover will occur.

If you want the file to rollover while the application is running then you need to have a triggering policy that does that. One of SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy, TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy or CronBasedTriggeringPolicy will do the trick.

I suggest you review the configuration and RollingFileAppender sections of the manual one more time.